# Forward requests to minikube ip (how to access application deployed in minikube from remote computer)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, portforwarding

There are two machines in my local network. Computer 1 (192.168.1.100) is a common Windows machine. Computer 2 (192.168.1.200) has Debian, Docker engine and Minikube. Minikube ip is 192.168.49.2. I set up an Ingress controller for my k8s cluster and run app deploy with service, which is linked to ingress.
Now I would like to access from my computer 1 to the deployed application. It looks like I need ip/port forwarding from the computer 2 ip to minikube ip. I tried nginx (as a reverse server) and iptables, however no success.
Please let me know if I am wrong in my judgement and advise how to get access from computer 1 to my application deployed in minikube k8s cluster.

Comment: What virtualization software are you using? If you are using VirtualBox, there is an option of forwarding ports of your host machine to a port on your Virtual Machine's NAT address. Settings > Network > Advanced > Port Forwarding

Comment: You can use this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengsettingupingresscontroller.htm) for other troubleshooting steps to use. Also, add the test results on your post for better understanding.

Comment: @sekthor, I am using docker engine for virtualization.

Comment: @AlexG, thank you for the link. This link is about Ingress itself. Ingress is working fine. The problem is how to forward requests to this Ingress that coming to the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the issue. Just created Nginx server as a reverse-proxy with the following config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my-web-site.com;
  location / {
    include '/etc/nginx/proxy_params';
    proxy_pass http://192.168.49.2:80/;
  }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name my-web-site.com;

        ssl_certificate          /home/myuser/cert/file.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key      /home/myuser/cert/file.key;

       location / {
               proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
               proxy_pass         https://192.168.49.2:443;
       }

}
```